# asynchronous web response windows phone 8

Tags: asynchronous

This is the code I use to download an URL as html. The thing is, is there any way I can do
this asynchronous? the problem I want to know whether the response is successful and what is in the response before the program continues. It would be perfect if you could await client.DownloadStringAsync and a task.delay won't always work besides I don't like that idea of setting an standard time to wait. Thank you!

```
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

Comment: don't use asynchronous, then. use synchronous, which will block until the operation completes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions.

The first one (which I recommend) is to use the [Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) and change your code to use the new `HttpClient` instead of the old `WebClient`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

The second solution will allow you to continue using `WebClient`, so it may work as a temporary fix if you have a lot of other code depending on `WebClient`. To use `async` with `WebClient`, install the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/), and then you can use `DownloadStringTaskAsync`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
```