# Windows Phone ScheduleAgent grabbing images on set period

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm attempting to follow an [Windows Phone tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8), tweaking it a bit to fit my needs. I am trying to grab a new picture every X seconds (30 for debugging) and set it as the new lockscreen background. I created a ScheduleAgent object to call it, however, it seems to be skipping a function. It *does not* skip this when in the `MainPage.xaml.cs`, which runs the exact same function.

**ScheduleAgent.cs**

```
        static ScheduledAgent()
    {
       ....<irrelevant code>....

    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {

        .... < Code went here that shouldn't matter > ....
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Imagename = " + imageName);


            DownloadImagefromServer("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qoutescreen/0" + imageName + ".jpg");
```

m.ReleaseMutex();
            }

```
        // If debugging is enabled, launch the agent again in one minute.
        // debug, so run in every 30 secs
        #if(DEBUG_AGENT)
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Periodic task is started again: " + task.Name);
        #endif

        // Call NotifyComplete to let the system know the agent is done working.
        NotifyComplete();
    }
    //===============================================================================
    private async void LockScreenChange(string filePathOfTheImage, bool isAppResource)
    {
        if (!LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
        {
            // If you're not the provider, this call will prompt the user for permission.
            // Calling RequestAccessAsync from a background agent is not allowed.
            await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        }

        // Only do further work if the access is granted.
        if (LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
        {
            // At this stage, the app is the active lock screen background provider.
            // The following code example shows the new URI schema.
            // ms-appdata points to the root of the local app data folder.
            // ms-appx points to the Local app install folder, to reference resources bundled in the XAP package
            var schema = isAppResource ? "ms-appx:///" : "ms-appdata:///Local/";
            var uri = new Uri(schema + filePathOfTheImage, UriKind.Absolute);

            // Set the lock screen background image.
            LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);

            // Get the URI of the lock screen background image.
            var currentImage = LockScreen.GetImageUri();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The new lock screen background image is set to {0}", currentImage.ToString());                
        }
    }
            private async Task DownloadImagefromServer(string imgUrl)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Attempting to Get Image from Server...");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            // I GET A "Cannot await Void" problem here?!?!?
            //=================================================================
            var result = await client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(imgUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);

        }

        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        //client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(imgUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER HIT WHEN RUN IN THE ScheduleAgent.cs CODE, HOWEVER
    // WHEN IT IS RUN INT HE MainPage.xaml.cs CODE (Which is a copy/paste) IT RUNS FINE
    // WHY IS IT NOT HITTING THIS? HOW CAN I FIX IT?
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(e.Result);
        //img.Source = bitmap;

        // Create a filename for JPEG file in isolated storage.
        String tempJPEG = "DownloadedWalleper.jpg";

        // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

            StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative);
            sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

            //BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            //bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
            Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

            //wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        LockScreenChange("DownloadedWalleper.jpg", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `DownloadImagefromServer` is asynchronous, so the method returns before the image is downloaded. Then you call `NotifyComplete`, which stops the execution of your background agent. Use a mutex to prevent the `OnInvoke` method from returning before the file has finished downloading.

Comment: But it is skipping the function call completely. So to me, it seems that it doesn't even try, not that it doesn't have enough time. Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: Well, set a breakpoint to be sure, but I don't see why it would skip the call

Comment: That's what I did. I set breakpoints all over the place and it seems to just be skipping right over it. That function is never hit, and I have not a clue why.

Comment: Oh wait, you mean `client_OpenReadCompleted` is never hit, right? I was thinking about `DownloadImagefromServer`. It's absolutely normal that it's never called, this event is triggered only when the download is complete (and the agent is exiting too early as I explained before)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, you'll have to excuse my ignorance. I tried setting up a mutex around the `DownloadImagefromServer` with a basic `mutexObj.waitOne()` and `mutexObj.ReleaseMutex()` and it still releases early. Suggestions?

Comment: @JcKelley I have some problem with instantiating a new BitmapImage object in the Scheduled Agent. It always throws an exception when I call the constructor. I tried to put all my code from the OnInvoke() method in a Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() call, but then all the WeClient downloads stopped working. Did you run into similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the "[await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)" keyword. This will cause the code to pause and wait for the action to complete without needing to worry about mutexes or other thread-blocking strategies.

Unfortunately Windows Phone is missing the non-async methods on WebClient, so there's a little bit of setup, blatantly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303204/173467).

> To use async with WebClient, install the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) NuGet package, and then you can use OpenReadTaskAsync

```
private async void DownloadImagefromServer(string imgUrl)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Attempting to Get Image from Server...");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    var result = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(imgUrl, UriKind.Absolute));

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(result);
    //img.Source = bitmap;

    ... rest of your code from OpenReadCompleted goes here
}
```

So what happens is that execution waits for the "OpenRead" call to complete before it processes the result and then returns control.

Comment: It's not recognizing `OpenRead` as a valid method for a webClient object? Do you think that's a separate issue or related?

Comment: Oops, you're right. Windows Phone only has the Async method. I've edited the answer. Await should still block the thread until the open is complete.

Comment: Seems it still isn't biting. "cannot await void", do I need to return a Task object?

Comment: Ah yes, you do. Sorry about all the mistakes. I'm not at a my computer with Visual Studio so can't compile

Comment: I tried that and I seem to be getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I finally got to a computer with Visual Studio and have got the above code to compile.

Comment: Gah, thank you so much good sir. This is quite the hassle for what (at least I would think) should be rather easy. Once the timer has expired, the bounty is yours.