# Stopping a WebClient after usage in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to stop WebClient after my usage but i couldn't find a way to do that.

```
public static WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
```

Comment: You have simply created WebClient object and did not start anything in the given code?

Comment: I think you want to `Dispose` rather then `Stop` since you say `after usage`

Comment: yes how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You could use:  [`CancelAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync.aspx)

For example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://example.com/parameter";
client.BeginDownloadString(uri);
client.CancelAsync();
```

Comment: it returns unhandled error my code is client.UploadStringCompleted += webClientfollow_UploadStringCompleted;
        
            client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", followinfo);

           // client.CancelAsync();

Comment: why dont you use async and await? follow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302746/asynchronous-web-response-windows-phone-8

Comment: do you have a working example for httpclient and what is different